# Testing express route methods

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to check whether res.json() is being called in a express get method.

However in my get method it waits for a promise before executing res.json();

Here is the controller method:

```
function get(req, res, next) {

    Service
        .doImportantThings()
        .then(success, error);

    function success(result) {
        res.json(result); // Method i want to test.
    }

    function error(error) {
        // Handles it
    }
}
```

Service:

```
function doImportantThings() {
    var deferred = q.defer();

    doStuff
        .then(success, error);

    function success(results) {
        deferred.resolve(output);
    }

    function error() {
        deferred.reject();
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Test:

```
    beforeEach(function () {
        var Service = require('../../../../app/services/service');
        ServiceMock = sinon.mock(Service);
        methodExpect = ServiceMock.expects('doImportantThings').returns(q.resolve("test"));
        res.json = sinon.spy();

        expressController = require('../../../../app/controllers/v1/controller');
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        ServiceMock.restore();
    });

    describe('get()', function () {

        it('should call res.json() one time', function () {
            expressController.get(req, res);    
            expect(res.json).to.have.been.calledOnce; // Fails 
        });

        it('should call res.json() with object argument.', function () {
            expressController.get(req, res)
            expect(res.json).to.have.been.calledWith("test"); // Fails


        });

    });
```

Because i'm using promises the expect always returns false. I've tried to use mocha's done() callback with no success. I have also tried to put a callback as a controller parameter and call done from there or do the expect there but the test either times out or doesn't assert.

All the answers i have found talk about using supertest which would probably work but i want to be able to test this without making a http request to the resource to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tackled the same problem and in the end decided to wrap my 'get' method in a promise, allowing my test to complete once the promise resolves. I call res.send in my route. I've moved my logic out of my routes file into a separate file, which it looks like you might also have done. So, this in effect is what I currently have:

/routes.js

```
var routeMethods = require('./methods');

router.get('/get-data/:id', function(req, res) {

    routeMethods.getTheData(req.params.eventId).then(

        (result) => {
            res.status(result.statusCode).send(result.response);
        });
    });
}
```

/methods.js

```
var externalTools = require('./externalTools.js');

var routeMethods = {

    getTheData: function (id) {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            externalTools.getDataFromExternalService(id)

                .then((externalResponse) => {

                    resolve({'statusCode': externalResponse.statusCode,
                             'response': externalResponse.body});

                }, (errorDetails) => {

                    reject({'statusCode': errorDetails.statusCode,
                            'response': errorDetails.error + ' ' + id});

                });
        });
    }
};

module.exports = routeMethods;
```

/tests.js

```
var expect = require('chai').expect,
    request = require('request'),
    should = require('chai').should(),
    sinon = require('sinon'),
    methods = require('./methods');

describe('get data routes', function() {

    describe('getData', function() {

        it('should return the correct statusCode and error summary when theres a whapi error', function (done) {

            sinon
                .stub(request, 'get')
                .yields('404', {'statusCode': 404}, JSON.stringify({"faults": [{"faultCode": "10003","faultString": "Resource not found - test","faultName":""}]}));

            methods.getTheData('1234').then(

                (response) => {},
                (response) => {

                    expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(404);
                    done();
                });

            request.get.restore();

        });

    });

});
```